# When to exclude erroneous data point

Tags: measurement-error

Let's say that I have two data sets, A and B-- A records the number of oak trees across fifteen plots in one habitat, B records the number of oak trees across fifteen plots in a different habitat.

```
           A    B
Plot  1    0    0
Plot  2    0    0
Plot  3    0    1
Plot  4    0    0
Plot  5    0    0
Plot  6   10    0
Plot  7   12    0
Plot  8    0    5
Plot  9    0    0
Plot 10    0    7
Plot 11    0    0
Plot 12    7    0
Plot 13   20    0
Plot 14   22    1
Plot 15    0   12
Plot 16    6   19
```

If I run a t.test in R, I get the following output:

```
Welch's Two-Sample t-test

data:  A and B
t = 0.63289, df = 29.578, p-value = 0.5317
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -2.925367  5.550367
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
   4.1250    2.8125
```

That seems fine and dandy, but there is an issue with the data to begin with-- I noticed that seven of the zero's in set A and one zero in set B is the result of tree misidentification. In other words, we don't know how many trees are there (or not), because we could not accurately measure their abundance.

I suppose that my question is: If data points (independent of how they affect your data) are the result of error (not chance, but error), is it justifiable to exclude those from the analyses?

Answer (score 1):

If you know that there are actual errors in collecting certain data points then it would be wrong to include them in your analysis. You don't seem to be in the situation that leads to problems, which is when someone notices an outlier, just examines that for collection errors, but doesn't do the same for all data points. If you systematically examined all your data and identified errors in collecting some, then remove them.

Remember that you are trying to draw inferences about populations of plots of trees. If your data don't represent those populations correctly your inferences will be faulty.

Answer (score 1):

In general, when I analyze data, I never remove data from an analysis unless I can prove, either through an investigation of the data collection process or through deduction by use of the rest of the data, that the data point is missing completely at random.  Sometimes a data value can be set to missing or removed if it's an impossibility too.  For example, if you conducted a survey and you have several data points that indicate the respondent was pregnant, but you know for a fact that the respondent is male, then the data point could be reliably marked as missing, but the observation would not be *removed* because we could deduce the answer - "no" or "not applicable" and other values might be present for other analyses).

It is critical that you understand *why the data is missing*, even if in error.  If the error is completely random, then it's safe to set the values to missing and for the current analysis "remove" the observation, although you probably wouldn't want to remove the observation from the entire dataset if multiple analyses were intended and the observation contained other information.  If however, there is a chance that the missing mechanism is somehow related to your variables of interest, then you must take precautions not to bias your findings.  For example, say that you have a laboratory where you analyze specimens and from time to time, lab personnel accidentally drop test tubes and spoil the sample.  This is clearly the result of a random process and all specimens have an equal chance of being dropped (usually), so you could safely exclude the observation from your data.  Now, however, let's suppose that much more additional testing is performed when specimens test positive for certain characteristics.  If the laboratory is poorly set up and the specimen must be moved from table to table and there are obstacles in the way during additional testing, that could lead to an increased chance of the specimen being dropped or spoiled.  Then it would generally be a bad idea to simply remove the observations.  The very fact that some of the data is missing on this specimens provides some information on the probabilities that the specimen tested positive for the specific characteristic previously mentioned.  So instead of removing the data point, one should set the missing values to "missing" and then try to estimate the missing values, by modeling the missing data itself, if possible.  The same applies to errors.  If the observations are in error completely at random, you could safely ignore them.  Otherwise, you'd proceed differently during the analysis.

As you can see, being able to properly classify why your data is missing is important before performing an analysis.  Generally, statisticians distinguish between three types of missing values:  Missing Completely at Random (MCAR), Missing at Random (MAR), and Missing Not at Random (MNAR).  You typically proceed with your analysis differently depending on what type of missing data you have.  This [article](https://www.theanalysisfactor.com/missing-data-mechanism/) does a pretty good job at simply explaining these and you can find additional details on how to handle missingness by searching CV.

One final point that I'd like to make is that it's often useful to run any analyses both with all your data and then with your data removed.  If your results, don't change, then great.  If you performed the rest of your analysis correctly, then you can be confident in your results.  If they've changed, caution is warranted.